# Handle single server and multiple clients in c++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I am totally new to socket programming.I'm trying to understand the different practices when it comes to socket programming and handling multiple connections.
I have achieved the following functionality so for.

- server connect to multiple clients. c1,c2,c3......cn.
- server send a time-slot to client.
- server send message to client for transmitting message.(to transmit
  message in limited duration)
- client send message within limited time period
- once first connected client is time over server send message to next 
  client for transmitting message and so.

Here is my working code.

Server.cpp

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include<conio.h>

    #define DEFAULT_NC_TIME  20
    #define MAX_CLIENTS 2
    SOCKET Connections[MAX_CLIENTS];
    int TotalConnections = 0;

    #include <vector>
    #include<time.h>


void wait ( int seconds )
{
    clock_t endwait;
    endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
    while (clock() < endwait) {}
}

void ClientHandlerThread(int index) //index = the index in the SOCKET Connections array
    {
    int bufferlength; //Holds the length of the message a client sent
    while (true)
    {
        recv(Connections[index], (char*)&bufferlength, sizeof(int), NULL); //get buffer length
        char * buffer = new char[bufferlength+1]; //Allocate buffer
        buffer[bufferlength] = '\0';
        recv(Connections[index], buffer, bufferlength, NULL); //get buffer message from client
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        delete[] buffer; 
    }
    }

void emitMessageToClient(int indexOfClient, int ts){
        std::string buftest="You are ready to transmit Message.\n";
        int size = buftest.size(); //Get size of message in bytes and store it in int size
        send(Connections[indexOfClient], (char*)&ts, sizeof(int), NULL); //send Timeslot Duration to the client i
        send(Connections[indexOfClient], (char*)&size, sizeof(int), NULL); //send Size of message
        send(Connections[indexOfClient], buftest.c_str(), buftest.size(), NULL); //send Message
        }


int main()
    {
    //Winsock Startup
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "WinSock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111); 
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN); 

    SOCKET newConnection; //Socket to hold the client's connection
    int ConnectionCounter = 0; //# of client connections
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++)
    {

        newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen);
        if (newConnection == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to accept the client's connection." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Client "<<i<<" Connected!" << std::endl;
            Connections[i] = newConnection; 
            TotalConnections += 1; //Increment total # of clients that have connected
        }
    }

    int ts = DEFAULT_NC_TIME / (TotalConnections + 1); // caculating time slot for each of connected node including server 
    std::cout<<"\nPress any key to start transmission: ";
    getche();
    for(int i= 0; i < TotalConnections; i++){

        emitMessageToClient(i, ts);
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ClientHandlerThread, (LPVOID)(i), NULL, NULL);
        wait(ts);
        if(i == (TotalConnections - 1)){
           i = 0;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Client.cpp

```
        #include "stdafx.h"
    #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Required for WinSock
    #include <WinSock2.h> //For win sockets
    #include <string> //For std::string
    #include <iostream> //For std::cout, std::endl, std::cin.getline
    #include <time.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <conio.h>
    SOCKET Connection;//This client's connection to the server

    void wait ( int seconds )
    {
        clock_t endwait;
        endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
        while (clock() < endwait) {}
    }

    void ClientThread()
    {
        int bufferlength; //Holds the length of the message we are receiving
        int ts; // holds timeslot duration for this client
        while (true)
        {
            recv(Connection, (char*)&ts, sizeof(int), NULL); //receive timeslot
            recv(Connection, (char*)&bufferlength, sizeof(int), NULL); //receive bufferlength
            char * buffer = new char[bufferlength+1];
            buffer[bufferlength] = '\0'; 
            recv(Connection, buffer, bufferlength, NULL);
            std::cout << buffer << std::endl; //print out buffer
            std::string userinput; //holds the user's chat message

            for (int n= ts; n>0; n--)
           {
            userinput = "First client sending message...";
            int bufferlength = userinput.size(); //Find buffer length
            send(Connection, (char*)&bufferlength, sizeof(int), NULL); //Send length of buffer
            send(Connection, userinput.c_str(), bufferlength, NULL); //Send buffer
            wait (1);
           }
            delete[] buffer; //Deallocate buffer
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        //Winsock Startup
        WSAData wsaData;
        WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
        if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0)
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            return 0;
        }

        SOCKADDR_IN addr; 
        int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
        addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

        Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
        if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeofaddr) != 0)
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to Connect", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            return 0; //Failed to Connect
        }

        std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ClientThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        getche();
        return 0;
    }
```

once server send message to all his connected clients.Server wants to send message again to his **First client** to transmit message again.(cyclically)

**Problem**

How can I achieve if server talk all his clients c1,c2,c3 to Cn and again talk to his first client C1.(cyclically) I have used this check

```
 if(i == (TotalConnections - 1)){
       i = 0;
 }
```

but it crash the program.

Comment: Try using `threads`

Comment: Use a thread pool with a job queue.

Comment: @daemon7osh Above code is working fine. when I use if check it crash the program.I think on client side CreateThread function not handling efficiently

Comment: @Richard Critten can you give me the example ?

Comment: create thread per client serverside

Comment: That won't be the cause of the crash, it is elsewhere. That will, however, make it not start with the first client since you assign i to zero and then the loop immediately increases its value. Run the code in a debugger to see why and where it crashes.

Comment: By setting `i` back to 0 you create an infinite loop

Comment: One problem is that the second time around the loop you're creating new `ClientHandlerThread` threads for each client, even thought the threads you created the first time around are still running.  That might crash the server eventually I guess when it runs out of memory.  Instead, have a separate loop (that runs only once) to create the `ClientHandlerThread` threads.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `i` back to `0` you create an infinite loop because `i` never gets large enough for the loop to end.

```
for(int i= 0; i < TotalConnections; i++) {

    emitMessageToClient(i, ts);
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ClientHandlerThread, (LPVOID)(i), NULL, NULL);
    wait(ts);

    // This will create an infinite loop
    if(i == (TotalConnections - 1))
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

What you can do is wait until the loop has finished to re-visit the first connection:

```
for(int i= 0; i < TotalConnections; i++) {

    emitMessageToClient(i, ts);
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ClientHandlerThread, (LPVOID)(i), NULL, NULL);
    wait(ts);
}

// now the loop is over, revisit the first connection 
// if it exists      
if(TotalConnections > 0) {

    emitMessageToClient(0, ts);
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ClientHandlerThread, (LPVOID)(0), NULL, NULL);
    wait(ts);
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like the OP *wants* an infinite loop.  I don't think that's the problem.